# Should I edit my old unanswered question or start a new one?

Tags: discussion

I have posted a question four months ago which could not be answered because of missing information on my side. I have now collected additional data (network monitoring diagrams that prove the problem).

Should I add the new information to the old question? Will the edited post show up just as other new questions? Or will the edited post stay way down in the questions queue so that there is only a slight chance of anybody seeing it?

The question is here: [will heavy network traffic affect other connections on HP ProCurve V1810-48G?](https://serverfault.com/questions/423711/will-heavy-network-traffic-affect-other-connections-on-hp-procurve-v1810-48g)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Editing it with new information will bump it up. Also consider adding a bounty if necessary. Editing is preferable to asking a new, identical question

Comment: Always this. Writing a new question that duplicates an old one you've written is likely to see your new question closed as a duplicate of the old one on pretty much all the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: And having a question closed as a duplicate of one that is also closed is really annoying. :)

Comment: Editing a closed question _also_ automatically puts it into the reopen review queue.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Only once? Or repeatedly, if the first edit was insufficient to get it reopened?

Comment: Best to do it once, and do it right ;). People would get annoyed at constant *unnecessary* bumping. Edits should be substantial rather than minor. If you're *really* lucky, you might find your own answers.

Comment: @kasperd I _think_ it only gets one shot.